# Do a random action after clicking on Flutter

Tags: flutter, random

hello i am new to flutter,

i want to program a button which after i click it does a random "void" action. Does anybody has an idea how to write something like this on flutter?
i couldn't find anything related to my issue.

My code rigth now is something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart: math';
//Startpage etc...
class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  void ActionA() //...
  void ActionB() //...
  void ActionC() //... 

  return Scaffold(
   //appBar etc...
    FlatButton(
     color: Colors,blueGrey,
     onPressed: //now it should do randomly one of the voids 
    )
}
```

sry for my bad english but i gave my best...

Comment: Why would you want to execute a random function that does nothing? Do you mean that you want to execute a random method from a list of defined methods whenever you click the button?

Comment: yes i guess... i am really new to this topic so sry if some parts of my question is unclear.

Comment: @Nicolas, check my answer below, if it does what you want (I'm sure it is), then mark is as accepted, thanks

Comment: After you made the edit, your question is pretty clear. @Nonstapp has given a good answer. You can follow the approach.

Comment: Thanks @nonstapp for the good answer. It works now as i want it to be! And as your asked i am working on an app for learning different bird calls and i needed a possibillity to play a random voice so i can guess which species it is from. Like with flashcards

Comment: I see, ok thanks. Next time write the purpose, because like that some people downvoted your question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think user should know what is he doing by clicking a button, but if You really want this to work I would suggest you something like this:

On your on pressed method in button write this

```
onPressed: () {
   final randomInt = Random().nextInt(3);

   if (randomInt == 0) {
     _randomAction1();
   } else if (randomInt == 1) {
     _randomAction2();
   } else {
     _randomAction3();
   }
},
```

And define this methods like:

```
  void _randomAction1() {
    print('Random action 1');
  }

  void _randomAction2() {
    print('Random action 2');
  }

  void _randomAction3() {
    print('Random action 3');
  }
```